# How to extract the CSS used by each component of a Vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2

**Description**

My Vue 2 project is using bootstrap and an additional UI kit on top of that. Editing the css of my components is difficult due to how abstracted the variables are in the UI kit.

**Looking For**

I want to extract the css used by each individual component, and dump it into its own file.

This would allow me to create styled components, but get rid of bootstrap and the UI kit altogether.

**What I've tried**

I have searched NPM for a package that does this but have not found anything whatsoever.

I'm open to any methods to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, bit hasty:
open your vue page in browser

click on inspect element

select specific components and you will get css on it.

Comment: Yes, I have CSS SCAN in Chrome which does this to a degree, but the class names are often messed up, and it's highly time consuming. I would prefer to have this as an NPM package that just spits out my styled-components at build time.

Comment: Well i don't think there is any such thing, it would be great if such exists. It would help me also.

Answer (score 0):

As per I got the question understanding, you want the component css style applied on top(i.e. in priority), right?

```
 So, try it like 

<style scoped>

or else if by inspect element you find something like this :  [data-v-f3f3eg9] 

then try like /deep/ or ::v-deep before the class selector with the sample example:

 /deep/ .child-class {
    background-color: #000;
  }
```